# Problemas al guardar fecha PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, date, datetime

Tengo un proyecto en la web y estoy intentando guardar la fecha completa en la base de datos pero me esta dando un error extraño, no entiendo cual es el error.

**Nota:** hace poco todo marchaba bien por que en mi base de datos en el campo donde guardo la fecha era de tipo `DATE`  y me di cuenta de que nececito la fecha completa con horas y minutos, entonces cambié el formato a `DATETIME` después que lo cambie también cambié la función de la fecha, aquí veran un ejemplo

```
$fecha=date('Y-m-d');//antes 
$fecha=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');//nueva
```

Aclaro que estoy trabajando con consultas preparadas y esta es la forma en la que inserto la información

```
$query=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO noticias (titulo,fecha)VALUES(?,?)");
$sql->bind_param("sd", $titulo,$fecha);
if($sql->execute()){

  $sql->close();
    echo"exito";
}else{

   echo"error ".mysqli_error($con)
}
```

El error que me arroja es el siguiente

> **Error:** Incorrect datetime value: '2018' for column 'fecha' at row 1

Comment: Proba haciendo un bindParam por variable. (binParam va junto sin el guion bajo) Ej: $sql-> bindParam(":idUno", $idUno, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: lo siento pero como oudiste ver mis consultas preparadas son usando el driver mysqli

Comment: Estas indicando en `$sql->bind_param("sd", $titulo,$fecha);` que `$fecha` es de tipo double, cuando realmente **es un string**, debería ser `$sql->bind_param("ss", $titulo,$fecha);` es decir `"ss"` en lugar de `"sd"`, puedes revisar la documentación aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Que base de datos utiliza estimado? te interesa solo tomar la hora del servidor o se la pasas por parametro (un input tipo date)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si revisamos la documentación de [`msqli::bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) vemos que que existen cuatro carácteres para definir el tipo de variable:

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| i | la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero                 |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| d | la variable correspondiente es de tipo double                 |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| s | la variable correspondiente es de tipo string                 |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| b | la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

En este caso las fechas deben ser pasadas como un string (`s`) ya que el resto de tipos no se ajusta, actualmente lo indicas que es de tipo double, fijate:

```
$sql->bind_param("sd", $titulo,$fecha);
```

También te falta un punto y coma en:

```
   echo "error " . mysqli_error($con)
```

Así como algunos espacios que mejorarían la lectura del código en general

Por lo tanto tu código debería quedar así:

```
//$fecha=date('Y-m-d');//antes 
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //nueva

$query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO noticias (titulo, fecha) VALUES (?, ?)");
// indicamos que la variable titulo y fecha son de tipo string
$sql->bind_param("ss", $titulo, $fecha);

if($sql->execute()) {
    $sql->close();
    echo "exito";
} else {
    echo "error " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es pasar la fecha del sistema (que es lo que veo que estas haciendo) mas que pasar una fecha definida (por un campo post) lo que puedes hacer es enviar directamente la consulta para obtener el formato que corresponde para la base de datos es decir de la siguiente manera

```
$query=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO noticias (titulo,fecha)VALUES(?,?)");
$sql->bind_param("sd", $titulo,"CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()");
if($sql->execute()){

  $sql->close();
    echo"exito";
}else{

   echo"error ".mysqli_error($con)
}
```

lo que se hara es lo siguiente

```
INSERT INTO noticias (titulo, fecha) VALUES ('titulo', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

y lo que hara mysql es insertar el dato correspondiente al a fecha y hora del momento de la transacción

referencia (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_func_mysql_current_timestamp)

Comment: Buenas @pablo esto tal como lo expones no funcionara por el mismo motivo que no le funciona al op como lo tiene, **`bind_param()` hará una conversion a double antes de enviar el valor** por lo que `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` se convertira en `0` que es lo que se enviara a mysql. La idea no es mala y es viable si en lugar de pasar `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` atraves de `bind_param` se pasa directamente en la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Estás pasando la fecha como un doble y debe ser string, debes cambiar:

```
$sql->bind_param("sd", $titulo,$fecha);
```

por:

```
$sql->bind_param("ss", $titulo,$fecha);
```